# Text appear blurred in Chrome while using SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, svg

Chrome is rendering SVG text blurred where as it appears smooth in other browsers like IE 10. Please check below code. Can you please help?

```
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
    width="500" height="500" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <defs id="SvgjsDefs1001"></defs>
    <ellipse id="OuterCircle" rx="225" ry="225" cx="230" cy="230"
        stroke="#ffdc00" stroke-width="10" fill="#ffffff"></ellipse>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1003" d="M230,230  L229,20  A210,209 0 0,1 274,24 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="0" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="1"
        title="Personal presentation"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1004"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="end" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="0"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Personal pres..." x="425" y="235"
        title="Personal presentation" transform="rotate(-84 230,230)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1016"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="425">Personal pres...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1017" d="M230,230  L274,24  A210,209 0 0,1 317,39 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="1" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="2"
        title="Meeting preparation"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1018"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="end" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="1"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Meeting prepa..." x="425" y="235"
        title="Meeting preparation" transform="rotate(-72 230,230)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1030"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="425">Meeting prepa...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1031" d="M230,230  L317,39  A210,209 0 0,1 356,62 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="2" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="3" title="Rapport"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1032"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="end" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="2"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Rapport" x="425" y="235" title="Rapport"
        transform="rotate(-60 230,230)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1037"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="425">Rapport</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1038" d="M230,230  L356,62  A210,209 0 0,1 389,93 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="3" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="4" title="Introductions"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1039"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="end" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="3"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Introductions" x="425" y="235"
        title="Introductions" transform="rotate(-47 230,230)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1050"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="425">Introductions</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1051"
        d="M230,230  L389,93  A210,209 0 0,1 415,131 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="4" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="5" title="Set agenda"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1052"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="end" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="4"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Set agenda" x="425" y="235"
        title="Set agenda" transform="rotate(-35 230,230)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1060"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="425">Set agenda</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1061"
        d="M230,230  L415,131  A210,209 0 0,1 432,173 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="5" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="6"
        title="Specify client needs"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1062"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="end" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="5"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Specify client..." x="425" y="235"
        title="Specify client needs" transform="rotate(-22 230,230)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1075"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="425">Specify client...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1076"
        d="M230,230  L432,173  A210,209 0 0,1 439,218 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="6" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="7"
        title="Company background "></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1077"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="end" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="6"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Company back..." x="425" y="235"
        title="Company background " transform="rotate(-10 230,230)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1088"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="425">Company back...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1089"
        d="M230,230  L439,218  A210,209 0 0,1 437,263 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="7" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="8"
        title="Position company"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1090"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="end" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="7"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Position comp..." x="425" y="235"
        title="Position company" transform="rotate(3 230,230)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1102"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="425">Position comp...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1103"
        d="M230,230  L437,263  A210,209 0 0,1 425,307 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="8" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="9"
        title="Sales Value Proposition"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1104"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="end" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="8"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Sales Value Pr..." x="425" y="235"
        title="Sales Value Proposition" transform="rotate(15 230,230)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1117"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="425">Sales Value Pr...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1118"
        d="M230,230  L425,307  A210,209 0 0,1 404,347 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="9" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="10"
        title="Company offerings"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1119"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="end" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="9"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Company offe..." x="425" y="235"
        title="Company offerings" transform="rotate(27 230,230)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1130"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="425">Company offe...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1131"
        d="M230,230  L404,347  A210,209 0 0,1 374,382 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="10" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="12"
        title="Product/Service knowledge"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1132"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="end" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="10"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Product/Serv..." x="425" y="235"
        title="Product/Service knowledge" transform="rotate(40 230,230)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1143"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="425">Product/Serv...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1144"
        d="M230,230  L374,382  A210,209 0 0,1 338,409 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="11" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="13" title="Anecdotes"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1145"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="end" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="11"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Anecdotes" x="425" y="235" title="Anecdotes"
        transform="rotate(52 230,230)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1152"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="425">Anecdotes</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1153"
        d="M230,230  L338,409  A210,209 0 0,1 297,428 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="12" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="14" title="Case study"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1154"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="end" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="12"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Case study" x="425" y="235"
        title="Case study" transform="rotate(65 230,230)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1162"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="425">Case study</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1163"
        d="M230,230  L297,428  A210,209 0 0,1 253,438 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="13" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="15"
        title="Marketplace understanding"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1164"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="end" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="13"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Marketplace u..." x="425" y="235"
        title="Marketplace understanding" transform="rotate(77 230,230)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1176"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:end;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="425">Marketplace u...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1177"
        d="M230,230  L253,438  A210,209 0 0,1 207,438 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="14" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="16"
        title="Differentiation from competition"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1178"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="14"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Differentiation..." x="249" y="436"
        title="Differentiation from competition"
        transform="rotate(-91 234,439)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1192"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="249">Differentiation...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1193"
        d="M230,230  L207,438  A210,209 0 0,1 163,429 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="15" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="17"
        title="Discuss value"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1194"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="15"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Discuss value" x="203" y="432"
        title="Discuss value" transform="rotate(-78 188,435)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1205"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="203">Discuss value</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1206"
        d="M230,230  L163,429  A210,209 0 0,1 122,410 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="16" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="18"
        title="Create solution on the fly"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1207"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="16"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Create solutio..." x="160" y="419"
        title="Create solution on the fly" transform="rotate(-66 145,422)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1220"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="160">Create solutio...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1221"
        d="M230,230  L122,410  A210,209 0 0,1 85,382 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#00a652" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="17" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="19"
        title="Objection-handling"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1222"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="17"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Objection-han..." x="121" y="396"
        title="Objection-handling" transform="rotate(-53 106,399)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1234"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="121">Objection-han...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1235" d="M230,230  L85,382  A210,209 0 0,1 56,348 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="18" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="21"
        title="Next steps/timescales"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1236"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="18"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Next steps/tim..." x="87" y="371"
        title="Next steps/timescales" transform="rotate(-41 72,368)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1249"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="87">Next steps/tim...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1250" d="M230,230  L56,348  A210,209 0 0,1 35,308 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="19" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="24"
        title="Meeting management"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1251"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="19"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Meeting mana..." x="61" y="334"
        title="Meeting management" transform="rotate(-29 46,331)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1262"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="61">Meeting mana...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1263" d="M230,230  L35,308  A210,209 0 0,1 22,264 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="20" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="25"
        title="Qualification"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1264"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="20"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Qualification" x="43" y="293"
        title="Qualification" transform="rotate(-16 28,290)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1275"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="43">Qualification</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1276" d="M230,230  L22,264  A210,209 0 0,1 20,218 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="21" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="84"
        title="Sales person's conduct"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1277"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="21"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Sales person'..." x="35" y="248"
        title="Sales person's conduct" transform="rotate(-4 20,245)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1289"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="35">Sales person'...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1290" d="M230,230  L20,218  A210,209 0 0,1 27,174 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="22" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="85"
        title="Understanding pains"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1291"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="22"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Understanding..." x="37" y="203"
        title="Understanding pains" transform="rotate(9 22,200)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1303"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="37">Understanding...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1304" d="M230,230  L27,174  A210,209 0 0,1 44,131 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="23" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="86"
        title="Match customer pain to the offering"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1305"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="23"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Match custom..." x="48" y="159"
        title="Match customer pain to the offering"
        transform="rotate(21 33,156)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1316"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="48">Match custom...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1317" d="M230,230  L44,131  A210,209 0 0,1 69,94 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#00a652" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="24" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="88"
        title="Differentiation from competition when challenged"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1318"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="24"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Differentiation..." x="68" y="118"
        title="Differentiation from competition when challenged"
        transform="rotate(34 53,115)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1332"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="68">Differentiation...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1333" d="M230,230  L69,94  A210,209 0 0,1 102,63 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#00a652" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="25" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="89"
        title="Closing the deal"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1334"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="25"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Closing the de..." x="97" y="83"
        title="Closing the deal" transform="rotate(46 82,80)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1347"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="97">Closing the de...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1348" d="M230,230  L102,63  A210,209 0 0,1 141,39 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="26" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="90"
        title="Close to the next stage"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1349"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="26"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Close to the n..." x="133" y="55"
        title="Close to the next stage" transform="rotate(58 118,52)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1362"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="133">Close to the n...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1363" d="M230,230  L141,39  A210,209 0 0,1 184,24 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#00a652" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="27" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="91"
        title="Price negotiation skills"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1364"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="27"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Price negotiat..." x="174" y="35"
        title="Price negotiation skills" transform="rotate(71 159,32)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1377"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="174">Price negotiat...</tspan></text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1378" d="M230,230  L184,24  A210,209 0 0,1 229,20 z"
        transform="translate(0,0)" fill="#82ca9c" stroke="#898a8b"
        stroke-width="0.5" data-type="path" data-id="28" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;" data-analysisgroupid="92"
        title="Negotiation througout the meeting"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1379"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        text-anchor="start" fill="#000000" data-type="competency" data-id="28"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px!important" leading="1.5"
        font-weight="bold" text="Negotiation th..." x="218" y="24"
        title="Negotiation througout the meeting"
        transform="rotate(83 203,21)">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1392"
        style="font-size:11px!important;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:start;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        dy="0" x="218">Negotiation th...</tspan></text>
    <ellipse id="WhiteCircle" rx="55" ry="55" cx="230" cy="230"
        stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill="#ffffff" cursor="pointer"
        style="cursor:pointer;"></ellipse>
    <ellipse id="allTextCircle" rx="45" ry="45" cx="230" cy="230"
        stroke-width="0" fill="#e6e7e9" style="fill: #ffe655;"></ellipse>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1395" width="90" height="8" x="185" y="225"
        fill="#ffffff"></rect>
    <text id="PercentageComplete"
        style="font-size:18px;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:middle;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        x="230" y="210" fill="#525658" font-family="Verdana" font-size="18px"
        text-anchor="middle" color="#525658" font-weight="bold">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1397" dy="0" x="230"
        style="font-size:18px;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:middle;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;">100%</tspan></text>
    <text id="SvgjsText1398"
        style="font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:middle;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;"
        x="230" y="220" fill="#525658" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11px"
        text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1399" dy="0" x="230"
        style="font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:middle;textLength:1;font-weight:bold;">Complete</tspan></text>
    <text id="AllText"
        style="font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:middle;textLength:1;cursor:pointer;font-weight:bold;"
        x="230" y="255" cursor="pointer" fill="#525658" font-family="Verdana"
        font-size="11px" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1401" dy="0" x="230"
        style="font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana;text-anchor:middle;textLength:1;cursor:pointer;font-weight:bold;">View All</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

The example above on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JCXBE/).

Comment: I would try to narrow down the problem and just supply a sample code example.  The complete code, before the edit, was completly un-readable.

Comment: Kindly post only the relevant code.

Comment: Looks fine for me and I'm using `Chrome: Version 31.0.1650.57` on a Macbook Pro

Comment: Looks fine for me on Chromium 23.0.1271.97

Comment: Try to be more specific about what OS (and version) you run and what version of Chrome you see this in. Anyway, it sounds like a bug that should be reported on http://crbug.com.

Comment: Mention Issue is replicate with  Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m and OS Windows 7 64 bit.